# $f(x , y)= \frac{x^3}{(x^2 + y^2)}$ if $(x , y) \neq (0 , 0)$. prove that f is continuous at any point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(0 , 0) =0$  &
    $f(x , y)= \frac{x^3}{(x^2 + y^2)}$ if $(x , y) \neq (0 , 0)$.  prove that f is continuous at any point. The restriction of $f$ to any straight line is differentiable.  Can it be proved by not using sequential criteria?

Can anyone help me out?

I know that $|f(x , y)| < |x|$...That's how we can show that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. But how can I show that the function is continuous at other points as well.

Comment: use operations on continuous functions (+,-,×,÷.

Comment: Possibly by verifying $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$?

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya Yes I was wrong, that is not a necessary condition.

Comment: Outside the origin the function is locally the composition of continuous functions.

Comment: But how?  Can u be more Specific? If all the functions were the functions of same independent variable then possibly u are right.@Rigel

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

Take polar coordinates: $$x=a+r\cos{\theta}$$ $$y=b+r\sin{\theta}$$

Keep in mind that  $r \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow (x,y) \rightarrow (a,b)$

and the final limit must be independent of $\theta$.

Lets compute it:

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}f(a+r\cos{\theta},b+r\sin{\theta})=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}=\frac{a^3+3r\cos{\theta}+3r^2 (\cos{\theta})^2+r^3 (\cos{\theta})^3}{a^2+b^2+2(ar\cos{\theta}+br\sin{\theta})+r^2}=\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$$

The last limit does not depend on $\theta$.

Comment: I really did not get you. Can you please elaborate?@Marios Gretsas

Comment: @cmi...just compute the limit when you change to polar coordinates..if the limit exists  in polar coordinates then exists in general..in the las two sentences i mentioned what happens when you change to polar coordinates..its like change of variable in a general limit

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the continuity at the origin by using polar coordinates and continuity on $\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is quite straight forward.

It is very handy to know the following results for multivariable functions, in fact it would be a good exercise to prove them.

> (1) The sum, difference and product of two continuous functions is always continuous.
>
> (2) The quotient of two continuous functions is continuous as long as the denominator is not $0$.
>
> (3) Polynomial functions are continuous.
>
> (4) Rational functions are continuous in their domains.
>
> (5) If $f(x,y)$ is continuous and $g(x)$ is defined and continuous on the domain of $f$ then $g(f(x,y))$ is also continuous.
>
> (6) Every projection map is continuous.

====================================================================

The function $f$ in your question is a rational function on $\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$

Thus by $(4)$ we have $f $ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$ and hence continuous on $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: But How?Can u be more Specific? If all the functions were the functions of same independent variable then possibly u are right.@Naive

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: If  the denominator and numerator were functions of same variables tthen U are right I think..

Comment: These results hold true for multivariable functions and they are not that difficult to prove either.

Comment: how? Prove it please..

Comment: Well $(1),(3),(6)$ are indeed very easy to prove, $(5)$ is a little tricky where you have to consider two functions and one way to prove it is by using the following definition of continuity:Inverse image of open sets is open. $(2),(4)$ are pretty much the same. Proving each of them rigorously will be very lengthy. Anyways these are standard results which you can find over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates:

$x = r\cos(\theta)$; $y= r\sin(\theta)$.

Define:

$f(r=0, \theta)= 0$, $0\le \theta \lt 2π$

and

$f(r,\theta) = r(\cos(\theta))^3 $,

for $0 \lt r$, $0 \le \theta \lt 2π$.

Consider:

$g(r):= r$, and $h(\theta) :=( \cos(\theta))^3$.

$g$ is continuous at any $r_0 \ge 0$.

$h(\theta)$ is continuous at any $\theta_0$ , $0 \le \theta_0 \lt 2π$.

At any point $(r_0,\theta_0)$:

$\lim_{r \rightarrow r_0} g(r)= r_0$, and

$\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \theta_0} h(\theta) = h(\theta_0)$.

Combining:

The product of $g$ and $ h$ ,

$f(r,\theta) = g(r)h(\theta)$ is continuous

at any point $(r_0,\theta_0)$,

in particular at the origin:

$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \theta_0} f(r,\theta) = 0 = f(r=0, \theta_0)$